# TortoiseSVN -- Icons are not displaying

Tags: windows-7, icons, svn, tortoise-svn, overlay

After TortoiseSVN bugged me to update, i downloaded a new installer and ran it. It still works fine now, though it does not properly display icon overlays (despite that option being on in the settings). How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've just updated to 1.6.8 (as I have), you might have to do a repair install to fix the icon overlay issue. As detailed on the [TortoiseSVN blog here](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/400).