# Tortoise won't display Status Icons

Tags: icons, tortoise-svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TortoiseSVN — Icons are not displaying](https://superuser.com/questions/135824/tortoisesvn-icons-are-not-displaying)

I updated my [Tortoise SVN client](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) today to

> TortoiseSVN 1.6.8, Build 19260 - 32
>   Bit , 2010/04/16 20:20:11 Subversion
>   1.6.11,  apr 1.3.8 apr-utils 1.3.9 neon 0.29.3 OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
>   zlib 1.2.3

However, I now don't see any Status icons for any folders/files.

The client still works as expected but it is a bit frustrating to not see a visual status.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Have you rebooted your system since the install?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/135824/tortoisesvn-icons-are-not-displaying I guess? Anyway, there's a link in that question to the tortoise homepage explaining you have to do a repair install.

Comment: Yep, it's a dupe. Thanks for pointing that out. The fix in the link you provided worked for me as I was having the same issue.